# Do Vitamin B1 patches prevent mosquito bites?

Tags: physiology, zoology

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is Vitamin B12 an effective mosquito repellent?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/6390/is-vitamin-b12-an-effective-mosquito-repellent)

This [Denver Post article](http://www.denverpost.com/extremes/ci_12668273) suggests that mosquitoes dislike biting people who have excess vitamin B1.

> The notion behind the Don't Bite Me! patch is that mosquitoes don't eat vitamin B-1. So slap one of these clear transdermal skin patches on a hairless spot two hours before going out to play with the bloodsuckers, and the excess of B-1 it builds up in your body supposedly will keep them at bay.

Is it true?

Comment: Related: http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/6390/is-vitamin-b12-an-effective-mosquito-repellent

Comment: I'm closing as a duplicate of *Is Vitamin B12 an effective mosquito repellent?* since the answer of that answers this one.